# Does it ever matter where a matrix job builds?

Tags: jenkins

When running a matrix / multi-config job, the first thing it does is launch a flyweight job which does nothing but spawn the specific axis jobs.

Does it ever matter where that flyweight job runs?  It doesn't seem to ever do anything other than launch the axis jobs.  Is there ever any reason to restrict where it can run?